# First Column not hiding in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and once I populate the view with the data source I hide the columns that I do not need.  For some reason the 1st column is not hiding.  I have checked the column name and they match and the 2nd line executes fine hides the column for the EVENTID.  I even did a messagebox.show(  dgvTourOther.Columns("OTHERID").name) and it returned the correct name.

```
dgvTourOther.Columns("OTHERID").Visible = False
dgvTourOther.Columns("EVENTID").Visible = False
```

Any idea what could cause a datagridview not to hide a column?  It is like some other property is locking that column..

The values being passed are all strings.  I do this on 3 other datagridviews ok but for somereason this gridview is acting different.  I am going to try an rearrange the columns and see if that helps.

Comment: What is the data type on the column that won't hide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember having this issue on a project a couple years ago. There were two potential solutions as I recall. The first was moving the .Visible setting code out of the Constructor (assuming thats where you have it now) and into something like the Form_Load event.

The second solution (which may have been what really worked for me) was to move the columns I wanted to hide to the end (right side) of the grid. Stupid I know.

Comment: I rearranged the columns on the gridview and now they all hide fine now.  I kept the column names the same but just rearranged them and put the two ID columns at the end.

I would still like to see if their is something else going on that I am not aware of.

Comment: @JPJedi - Like I said... I remember this from a project a couple years ago, so the details were fuzzy. I just remember it frustrated the heck out of me, and I never felt like I found a good reason. It may just be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Are the name of the column in datagridview same as that which are in the datasource. This can be a reason for this problem

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we clear the Datagridview columns and setting the columns property. In that case set DGV source after you defined the columns property.

```
            dgvProdGrp.DataSource = Nothing
    With dgvProdGrp.Columns
        .Clear()
        .Add(clsCommon.setTextColumn("prdg_id", "prdg_id", 0, 0, True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, ""))
        .Add(clsCommon.setTextColumn("prdg_name", "Group Name", 200, 1, True, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, ""))
    End With
    dgvProdGrp.DataSource = objDB.View_ProdGrp(1)
```