# DataGridView Column shows though marked invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DGV bound to a binding source generation code here.

```
            // dgvDocumentList
        // 
        this.dgvDocumentList.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dgvDocumentList.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dgvDocumentList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.dgvDocumentList.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgvDocumentList.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.dMTitleDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
        this.urlCol,
        this.idCol});
        this.dgvDocumentList.DataSource = this.docListFetchBindingSource;
        this.dgvDocumentList.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dgvDocumentList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.dgvDocumentList.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dgvDocumentList.Name = "dgvDocumentList";
        this.dgvDocumentList.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dgvDocumentList.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.dgvDocumentList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(336, 493);
        this.dgvDocumentList.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dgvDocumentList.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvDocumentList_CellContentDoubleClick);
        this.dgvDocumentList.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dgvDocumentList_SelectionChanged);
```

The Column code is here.

```
  // dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "DCBModLink";
        this.dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "DCBModLink";
        this.dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dCBModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = false;
        // 
        // dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "DCBID";
        this.dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "DCBID";
        this.dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
        this.dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dCBIDDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Visible = false;
        // 
        // eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        // 
        this.eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "EQModModelNumber";
        this.eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Model Number";
        this.eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "eQModModelNumberDataGridViewTextBoxCol
```

As you can see, the column definition for dcbModLinkDataGridViewTextBoxColumn says visble = false;
It also says this in the properties table. It still is visible in the application when run.

If I modify the postitions of the columns in the list I get the following results.  No changed other than the order they appear on the columns list.

DCBID(Visible)--DCBModLink(Invisible)--EQModModelNumber(Visible)

DCBModLink(Visble)--DCBID(InVisible)--EQModModelNumber(Visible)

EQModModelNumber(Visible)--EQModModelNumber(Invisible)--DCBID(Invisible)

I have masked the symptom of this issue by leaving the column that I want in the first slot but I dont know why this particular DGV is behaving this way.  There is another DGV on the same form that works fine no matter what position the columns are in.

I looked here: [First Column Not Hiding in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342107/first-column-not-hiding-in-datagridview), and here [datagridview id column will not hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359234/datagridview-id-column-will-not-hide)  But they just moved the problematice columns to the right like I did.

So. My questions are.

1. Are there other setting that I am not aware of that can override the visibility pararameter?
2. Has anyone else seen this and how did they stop it?

Comment: i had so many times face with it..you are not the first :)) in first times i delete the dgv-run and create from scratch-run.. this was helped me..but then i wrote an extension method and now no need to create..even no need to think to set dgv's size and scrolls ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use an extension method for this which is my own.. and works very well..also this method sets the dgv client height and width programmatically.. with this ext method just

1-)add dgv to your form

2-)create lists of columns and header texts as what you want to show the user

3-) call the method as `yourDGV.showTheGivenColumns(your params, yourparams, yourparams)`

P.S. : i changed the names to english and add summary in english..here is the code..

```
/// <summary>
  /// when this method called, it sets visible = false the columns where not in List of column names
  /// The column names List count and header List count must be the same number
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="dgvName">DGV which calls this ext method</param>
  /// <param name="Method">the data source load method of the DGV which calls this ext method</param>
  /// <param name="ColumnName">The columnNames List which contains the columns will show.. columnName List's type is List<string></param>
  /// <param name="Header">The list where you can set the dgv's headers as you prefer..it's type is also List<string></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public static DataGridView showTheGivenColumns(this DataGridView dgvName, object dataSourceLoadMethod, List<string> columnNameList, List<string> headerList)
            {
                dgvName.DataSource = null;
                dgvName.Columns.Clear();
                dgvName.DataSource = dataSourceLoadMethod;
                int j = columnNameList.Count;
                int m = 0;
                int s = headerList.Count;

                if (j == s)
                {

                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn d in dgvName.Columns)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                        {
                            if (d.Name == columnNameList[i])
                            {
                                d.HeaderText = headerList[i];
                                d.Visible = true;
                                d.Width = d.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, false);

                                m += d.Width;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                d.Visible = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Count of Header and ColumnName Lists are not equal..Please Check.");
                }
```

///after this line if your dgv has vertical and/or horizontal scroll, method will check and set the size with this option

```
bool vscroll = (dgvName.DisplayedRowCount(false) < dgvName.Rows.Count);
                bool hscroll = (dgvName.DisplayedColumnCount(false) < columnNameList.Count);
                if (vscroll == true)
                {
                    int vScrollWidth = (dgvName.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First()).Width;
                    dgvName.Width = m + (vScrollWidth + 5);
                }
                if ( vscroll == false)
                {
                    dgvName.Width = m + 5;
                }
                if (hscroll == true)
                {
                    int hscrollWidth = (dgvName.Controls.OfType<HScrollBar>().First()).Height;
                    dgvName.Height = ((dgvName.RowTemplate.Height * dgvName.RowCount) + dgvName.ColumnHeadersHeight) + hscrollWidth;

                }
                if (hscroll == false)
                {
                    dgvName.Height = ((dgvName.RowTemplate.Height * dgvName.RowCount) + dgvName.ColumnHeadersHeight) + 2;
                }

                dgvName.ClearSelection();
                dgvName.ReadOnly = true;
                return dgvName;
             }
```

***YOU MAY WANT TO KNOW THESE :***

1-) in your form if your dgv's size seems bigger than total columns then please set

```
d.GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, false);
```

method's `.AllCells` option to your form's needs.. if you set the `false` to `true` then your dgv will show the columns which flagged as half-showed..so we never need to change this ;)

2-) in checking the needs of scrollbar code part, the numbers which added to width or height are depends to screen resolution..the numbers which i add is not the best but as much optimized for 1024*768, 1280*800 and 1366*968 resolution..You may need to change these added numbers..

Comment: I will try this, but to me its the same as having to make sure the column order is correct.  If the parameter says dont show it, it shouldnt show it.

Comment: yeah it won't show.. if you won't need to check scrollbar.visible property then you can use the first part..but if you need then you can completely use the snippet..and before this snippet..i faced with some problems as you have..but after this..i forgot to have these problems..and this is very fast..in debug mode with VS2008 pro on win7 x64 core2duo @2Ghz 2Gb RAM and 64 MB video it takes only 1,350-370 millisecs extra time than normally loading of dgv..(SQLProfiler says so)..Please Consantrate on that : this is debug mode (you know release mode is faster up to % 30-45 than debug)