# Is there a worthwhile way to automatically adjust datagridview column widths?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want my DataGridView to show the entire header text (never clip or truncate it).

In some cases, I would also like it to do the same with the values in the columns, too (where they are relatively short values, such as "76 trombones", "3.141592653589793", "King of the wild frontier", etc.

I know that I can specifically refer to each column by name or index and set a value or a percentage, but I would prefer it to automatically size itself to be just wide enough for the entirety of the header text to display.

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode.aspx? It may seem like a silly question, but if you have it would be interesting to know what the effect of AutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells is on your presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension method (is my own) can answer your question  - even much more 
{ headers, visible / invisible columns, width, height and scrollbars } https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867026/967770

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the columns of your DataGridView and set its AutoSizeMode property like this:

```
 foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
 {
     column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
 }
```

There are other options in the DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode. The AllCells option adjusts all columns to fit the contents of all cells including the Header cell.

To implement this in your code, I suggest you put it in a Static Method so that you could reuse it and set columns for other DataGridViews:

```
 public static void SetColumns(DataGridView dgv)
 {
    foreach(DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
    {
       column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
    }
 }
```

You can add other general column modifications in there if you want like DefaultCellStyles, etc.